# How to re-order array with keys in another array?

Tags: php, arrays

What's the best way to re-order an array based on values in another array?

Array to be re-ordered:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [full_name] => Graham Smith
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [full_name] => Gerry Jones

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [full_name] => Frank Brown
        )

)
```

Order array:

```
(
    [0] => Jones
    [1] => Brown
    [2] => Smith
)
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Well, at first thought, you could use `usort` and an anonymous callback function that checks the position of $a and $b in your order array, and uses that to determine if it should return 1, 0, or -1.

Comment: I'd loop through the first array, explode each item on the space character, and search for the surname from the exploded string in the second array. I'd then build a results array using the found position from the search as an index to insert the full name. To do it this way, you'll need `explode` and `array_search`, plus `foreach` for looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very naive, straight-forward approach to do what you want

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array("full_name" => "Jack"),
    array("full_name" => "Bob"),
    array("full_name" => "Graham Smith"),
    array("full_name" => "Gerry Jones"),
    array("full_name" => "Frank Brown")
);

$order = array(
    "Jones",
    "Brown",
    "Smith"
);

function findOrderPosition($term) {
    global $order;

    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($order); $i++) {
        if ($term == $order[$i])
            return $i;
    }

    return -1;
}

usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    //Get the last names here (checking only the last space delimited token).
    $arra = explode(' ', $a['full_name']);
    $arrb = explode(' ', $b['full_name']);

    //Find the position in the $order array.
    $posa = findOrderPosition($arra[sizeof($arra) - 1]);
    $posb = findOrderPosition($arrb[sizeof($arrb) - 1]);

    if ($posa == -1) {
        return 1; //Couldn't find item $a in the order array, so we want to move $b ahead of it.
    }

    if ($posb == -1) {
        return -1; //Couldn't find item $b in the order array, so we want to move it to the bottom of the array.
    }

    if ($posa == $posb) {
        return 0; //Don't move the item up or down if they are equal.
    }

    return $posa > $posb ? 1 : -1; //If position of $a is greater than $b then we want to move $a up, otherwise, move it down.
});

print_r($array);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [full_name] => Gerry Jones
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [full_name] => Frank Brown
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [full_name] => Graham Smith
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [full_name] => Jack
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [full_name] => Bob
        )

)
```

Comment: This solution works although I found it a little complex for my level of PHP. Thanks for posting it as it help me find another solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution easier to understand although I don't know which solution performs best.

```
$array = array(
    array("full_name" => "Jack"),
    array("full_name" => "Bob"),
    array("full_name" => "Graham Smith"),
    array("full_name" => "Gerry Jones"),
    array("full_name" => "Frank Brown")
);

$order = array(
    "Jones",
    "Brown",
    "Smith"
);

$array_ordered = array();
$x = 0;
foreach ($order as &$find) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $row) { 
        $pos = strpos($row['full_name'], $find);
        if ($pos)  {
            $array_ordered[$x] = $array[$key];
        }
    }
    $x++;
}
print_r($array_ordered);
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it requires a name to be in the order list. What about names that aren't in the order list? Can you guarantee that they will always be in the order list?

Comment: Good point. Yes I can guarantee they will be in the list in my case.